# Entity Framework : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a WPF application, where I use SQL model. My application works fine excepting button "delete" on listview.

When I push the button "delete", I get an error

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity.

Please help

My page:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView SelectedItem="{Binding currentBoat}" ItemsSource="{Binding Boats}" Name="ListViewBoats" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      Margin="0,50,0,125">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Код_катера}"
            Header="Код катера" Width="100" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Название}"
            Header="Название" Width="100"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Тип}"
            Header="Тип" Width="150"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Водоизмещение}"
            Header="Водоизмещение" Width="150"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Дата_постройки, StringFormat='yyyy-MM-dd'}"
            Header="Дата постройки" Width="150"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <Button Name="AddBtn" Content="Добавить" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="198,355,0,0" Click="AddBtn_Click"></Button>
    <Button Name="DeleteBtn" Content="Удалить" Click="DeleteBtn_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="423,355,200,0"/>
</Grid>
```

My delete button:

```
private void DeleteBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var currentBoat = (sender as Button).DataContext as Катера;

    if (MessageBox.Show("Вы точно хотите выполнить удаление?", "Внимание!",
        MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        try
        {
            DBGaneevaEntities.GetContext().Катера.Remove(currentBoat);
            DBGaneevaEntities.GetContext().SaveChanges();

            ListViewBoats.ItemsSource = DBGaneevaEntities.GetContext().Катера.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try to delete data from listview and sql, my add button works good, i don't know how to realase delete button(

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to delete the currently selected item in the `ListView` (and not the `DataContext` of the clicked `Button`):

```
var currentBoat = ListViewBoats.SelectedItem as Катера;
```

Comment: thank you, I try to rewrite that and test

Comment: no, error is still there

Comment: Did you actually selected an item then? What is `ListViewBoats.SelectedItem` when you click in the button?

Comment: yes, i selected an item before i push my delete button

Comment: So `ListViewBoats.SelectedItem` is not a `Катера` then? Only you can tell what it actually is.

Comment: i just a beginner in this things and i'm russian, i don't understand

Comment: @yuliyagane: What type is `Boats`?